# How can I securely erase an iPod Classic?

Tags: itunes, security, ipod, ipod-classic

I have an **iPod Classic 120GB model A1238** ([Everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/specs/ipod-classic-late-2008-2g-specs.html)) that I'd like to ebay.

I discovered how to perform a **restore** both with and without a Mac. However, afterward my name still appears in the device's UI — "Nafine's iPod".

How can I ensure that all personal data is erased and overwritten, or as they say "wiped?"

Comment: Did you follow the docs here? - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252.

Comment: Manual for your model as well - https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1195/en_US/iPod_classic_160GB_User_Guide.pdf.

Comment: In addition to the reset you might try resetting the settings, they discuss it throughout the manual.

Comment: Agree with @slm — note that **“Factory restore” and “factory reset”** are two different things.

Comment: I mis-typed. I said "reset" but what I did was actually a **restore,** per the docs. I edited the question accordingly.